# Mock for a concrete class using gmock in C++

Tags: unit-testing, c++11, googlemock

I am stuck with creating a mock for a **concrete class**.

I know that is not a great idea to do this but **I'm not not allowed to change *production code***.

My code is similar with:

```
Class A
{
public:
        A(B* b)
        {
                this->b = b;
        }
.........................
 void function_from_a_to_test(<arg>)
{
        if(!b)
                b->function_from_b();
        else
             //something to do
}
private:
        B * b;
};

class B
{
........
 public:       
        void function_from_b();
......
};
```

```
class MockB : public B , testing::Mock //i don't know why I can that, B is not virtual 
{

 MOCK_METHOD(function_from_b, void, (void));

};


A_Test :testing::Test{
 SetUp()
{
        b = new B();
        a = new A(b);
}

 TearDown()
{
        delete b ;
        delete a ;
}

void set_b(B * bb)
{
        a->b = bb;
}

.........................
}

In order to test I used Test_f

TEST_F(A_Test, Test_function_from_a_to_test)
{
//arrange

//act
 B * b_t = new MockB();
set_b(b_t);
EXPECT_CALL(*(static_cast<MockB> b_t), function_from_b))
        .Times(10);

function_from_a_to_test(arg);
}
```

It's seems that the test is **passed** but i *got **memory leak** at static cast.*

And If I store the result of static cast in *another variable* (in order to delete it), the expect call having that variable is **failing**.

I know that is not really a good practice, but I can not change the production code.

Has somebody a idea how to solve it? 
Or a better way to test this?

Comment: The idea of "mocking" is generally not compatible with C++. You can sometimes restrict your C++ use, so that the resulting subset of C++ is compatible with mocking. But if you have existing C++ code that uses other C++ mechanisms, then that code cannot be "mocked". This is a fundamental design choice. C++ often is fast because the compiler knows exactly what's happening, while mocking relies on the compiler not knowing that and delaying the choice to runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock a non-virtual function using inheritance. You would have to have to define a mock class that implements the functions needed by the code under test, and then have a way to replace the concrete class with the mock class. Read more about it [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods).

To be honest, I have no idea what the result of that `static_cast` is, but it's probably not good.

The only way I can think of to do what you want to do *without changing production code* is to use a different include path in your test project that would allow completely replacing the concrete `class B` with the mock `class B`. This may or may not be possible, depending on how your production code is structured.

If you're lucky enough to have `class B` defined in a separate header file, then it's easy: Make a mock header file with the same name but different folder, and make sure that folder appears in the include path before the production header file's location.

Production `B.h` file (in original location and unmodified):

```
class B
{
public:
    void function_from_b() {}
};
```

Mock `B.h` file (in test code location):

```
class B
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, function_from_b, ());
};
```

Somewhere in production code (unmodified):

```
#include "B.h" // Will load original or mock depending on include path

class A
{
public:
    A(B *b)
    {
        m_b = b;
    }

    void function_from_a_to_test(int arg)
    {
        if (m_b)
            m_b->function_from_b();
        else
            ;    //something to do
    }

private:
    B *m_b;
}
```

Test code:

```
TEST(A_Test, Test_function_from_a_to_test)
{
    B b;
    A a(&b);

    EXPECT_CALL(b, function_from_b)
        .Times(1);

    a.function_from_a_to_test(0);
}
```